# XMLHttpRequest not terminating on DELETE request via proxy in IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, http-proxy

I have an Angular2 (2.0.1) application which calls a ReST API on a Jersey backend application. On Internet Explorer 11 the problem is that DELETE requests are execute correctly, but the callback is not executed immediately. Only after 120 seconds (i guess some timeout) the callback gets called. On network level I can see an immediate response, so I guess the problem is either in IE or in an Angular2 http library, probably only in case of a "204 No Content" reply.

[Edit]: Also GET requests behave this way in case of an empty response with 204 status.

As you can see in the developer tools, the request is pending for some time:
[image: Pending state]

After 120 seconds the request has finished. At this time the callback function is called:
[image: Finished after 120 seconds]

Note, that this happens only if the backend API is accessed through our corporate proxy, and only on IE 11.

The call is triggered as follows:

```
doDelete(id: string) {
    this.http.delete(this.deleteUrl + id)
        .subscribe(
            data => { this.ngOnInit(); },
            error => { window.alert(error) });
}
```

Here the network trace:

```
DELETE http://yyy.yyy.at/types/76856ad1-342c-41d0-a627-71cd02d586a8 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
authorization: Bearer b50cd05c-0314-4557-aa66-cf9c9f356e31
Referer: http://yyy.yyy.at/types
Accept-Language: de-AT
Origin: http://yyy.yyy.at
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 0
Host: yyy.yyy.at
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.0 204 No Content
Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 06:54:45 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yyy.yyy.at
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: 9047e7349d0e3de4224ae4053da5d560=b44c49344740b5a0b58b8fdd51b15bdc; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Cache: MISS from xxx.xxx.net
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from xxx.xxx.net:8080
X-Cache: MISS from xxx.xxx.at
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from xxx.xxx.at:8080
Via: 1.1 PSxxx, 1.1 xxx.xxx.net:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE9), 1.0 xxx.xxx.at:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: A workaround I found is to reply with code 200 instead of 204 and set "Content-Length: 0".

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 11 did this for me, too, but diligently making sure that the `Content-Length` was set to 0 fixed it for me, even with HTTP 204 as the response code.

If someone else experiences this problem, the easiest way to see if it is a timeout issue in Internet Explorer is to interrupt/restart your API server while IE is (incorrectly) waiting for data. Because the interruption will terminate the TCP connection, IE will inspect what data it has and try to make due -- after all, the status code says that there was a success, and since there is not actually supposed to be any content, your code will likely work anyway.

In my case, the timeout came after about 60 seconds, but that is likely due to my AWS Elastic LoadBalancer configuration keeping idle connections open for that long.